# like keyword in crystal report formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I tried to use like keyword in crystal report. 
There is an account number which always starts from "120" like 120348, 1208475, etc.

```
dcind account bank name amount  sale order
 D     120949   abc      73410
```

I use it like this:

```
{account_table.custno}='' and {account_table.saleorder}='' and {account_table.dcind} = 'D' 
and {account_table.account} like "120*"
```

I select amount from field and total summary "sum" and use in a formula field. I use the above formula and on reset I set account_no and then I drag this field on report, but in some column amount is visible and some column amount not visible.

Comment: You used this Chunk of code in some sort of condition? And then drag it on report? i don't Understand what you wants to achieve?

Comment: i select this by running total and then i drag this on report.

Comment: What are the colns where have you placed thise and in which fformula are you using that piece of code